# Capybara: Verify that ajax-loaded content is not present

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, selenium-webdriver

```
visit "/whatever"
expect(page).to have_no_content "This is loaded in asynchronously"
```

This should fail, but passes. Why? When the page first loads, the content isn't there, and Capybara reasonably doesn't wait for it.

What is the blessed way to wait for this content, now that Capybara 2.0 has declared `wait_until` bad news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
visit "/whatever"
wait_for_ajax do
  expect(page).to have_no_content "This is loaded in asynchronously"
end
```

Then, in `spec_helper`:

```
def wait_for_ajax
  page.evaluate_script("jQuery.active") == 0
  yield
end
```

This will evaluate the script until it is true, then run your assertion.

Answer (score 1):

```
visit "/whatever"
wait_for_ajax do
  expect(page).to have_no_content "This is loaded in asynchronously"
end
```

Then, in `spec_helper`:

```
def wait_for_ajax
  sleep(Capybara.default_wait_time)
  yield
end
```

Note that this waits to the end of Capybara's `default_wait_time` every time it runs this spec. But I'm not sure how else you'd check for something like that. If your ajax executes quickly, you can compensate for this by setting the `default_wait_time` to something like 1 second.

Comment: This page explains why wait_until was depreciated: http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara so with that said the page.should not_have methods will now use the capybara wait time effectively. chadoh's first example is my vote on dealing with ajax to load too, the second one - well my rule is to never use the sleep method. Its a sure fire way to make your tests slow.

Comment: The pages wait if content is currently present that you assert should not be, or if there's content that isn't present that you assert should be. But if you assert content isn't present, and it's not, it stops waiting there. It doesn't wait to check that the content isn't eventually loaded in via ajax. But I needed it to, in this case.

Comment: Aah I now get what you are trying to achieve. Try this link http://www.natontesting.com/2012/02/27/a-solution-to-ajax-errors-with-capybara-against-a-jquery-site/. Depending on your capybara version you may need to drop the wait_until. That way your step can wait for ajax to finish then assert.

Comment: @Dono thanks! That's exactly what I needed. I added a separate answer with the up-to-date solution, so future visitors need not hunt through comments and stale blog posts.

Comment: No worries man. I had massive battles with ajax not so long ago. this pretty much saved me :)